# tcpdump capture on port 80, but apache doesn't responds

Tags: apache

I have a problem that I don't understand.
See my configurations, port 80 is Listen on apache:

```
# grep -Rin Listen /etc/apache2/*
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:5:Listen 80
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/global.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName global.grupoconstruserv.com.br
        DocumentRoot /var/www/global
        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/global-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/global-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/global/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all Granted
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
  </IfModule>

</Directory>
# netstat -an|grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Firewall is ok:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http LOG level warning

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

tcpdump capture packts:

```
# tcpdump -nvvvi ens32 'port 80'
15:55:37.211374 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 6978, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    189.58.39.2.9656 > 192.168.1.12.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x46b1 (correct), seq 848450420, win 29200, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 4134684372 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:55:38.215987 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.1.12.80 > 189.58.39.2.9656: Flags [S.], cksum 0xa61f (incorrect -> 0x03bb), seq 1603885177, ack 848450421, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3782191690 ecr 4134684372,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:55:38.241102 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 6979, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    189.58.39.2.9656 > 192.168.1.12.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x45af (correct), seq 848450420, win 29200, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 4134684630 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

But on httping ou browser (on other device) returns timeout:

```
httping http://global.grupoconstruserv.com.br:80/ -t2
PING global.grupoconstruserv.com.br:80 (/):
connect time out
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
I have 2 routes. The packets was IN by one route and OUT by another route,
causing traffic loss.
So I adjusted to OUT to the same route that the packets IN.